# Bucketing value until it hits max buck sql

Tags: mysql, netezza

I am trying to bucket one single event into multiple buckets based on Max Hours. Pin here in my example has max hours of 1938. So it is bucketing it to 2000 range only with my query. 
But ideally, as the pin has reached 1938 hours, it must have had 500, 1000, and 1500 hours on it sometime in the past. So I am looking for a query that will assign this pin in not only <= 2000 bucket but in 500,1000,1500, and 2000 bucket.  So basically the logic should assign pin in all the buckets up until it hits its largest hour bucket. Please help.

My query

```html
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN "MAX HOURS" <= 500 THEN '500' 
 WHEN "MAX HOURS" <=1000  THEN '1000'
 WHEN "MAX HOURS" <=1500 THEN '1500'
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=2000 THEN '2000'
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=2500 THEN '2500'
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=3000 THEN '3000' 
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=3500 THEN '3500' 
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=4000 THEN '4000' 
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=4500 THEN '4500' 
 WHEN "MAX_HOURS" <=5000 THEN '5000'
ELSE 'OVER 5000'
END AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
```

[Current output]

```html
PIN   Max hours  Hours_Bucket
XYZ   1938.10       2000
```

Following is what I am expecting it to be: for all population of pins.I am not sure if and how to create a loop which would create following desired output.
[Expected result]

```html
PIN  Max hours  Hours_Bucket
XYZ  1938            500
XYZ  1938           1000
XYZ  1938           1500
XYZ  1938           2000
```

Comment: It would help to see the table you are querying, but I think you might just need to add `GROUP BY pin`.

Comment: wait... ignore my first comment. I read something wrong

Comment: Can we have that in English?

Answer (score 0):

I hate the way this query looks, but I'm not sure of another way to do this

```
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 500 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 1000 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 500
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 1500 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 1000
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 2000 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 1500
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 2500 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 2000
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 3000 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 2500
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 3500 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 3000
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 4000 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 3500
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 4500 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 4000
UNION ALL
SELECT PIN, `MAX HOURS`, 5000 AS Hours_Bucket
FROM PA_BTC
WHERE `MAX HOURS` > 4500
```

Comment: Thank you very much @CptMisery .It works except that it doesn't get included in the last max bin..what I mean by that is pin with 1938 hours get bucketed into 500(0-500),1000(500-1000),1500(1000-1500) with your query but it misses 2000(1500-2000) bucket as condition is > 2000 in the query. Is there any workaround for that max bucket for all pins that hit max bucket

Comment: I have edited my query. It is the same as the first, but I expanded it to include all of your buckets

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to be pretty easy now but didn't hit me before. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem. Sorry the query is ugly. Really not sure of another way to do it in SQL. Can you mark this as the answer? I need more of those sweet karma points

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility if you can use a small table (could be temporary or regular).

First, create a table to store the minimum hours required to qualify into the bucket. In your example, 1938 would qualify into 500 by being greater than 0, into 1000 by being greater than 500, etc.

Example of the table to create:

```
 create temp table bucket_max (
   max_hours_val int
 , max_hours character varying(10)
 );

 insert into bucket_max values (0,'500');
 insert into bucket_max values (500,'1000');
 insert into bucket_max values (1000,'1500');
 insert into bucket_max values (1500,'2000');
 insert into bucket_max values (2000,'2500');
 insert into bucket_max values (2500,'3000');
 insert into bucket_max values (3000,'3500');
 insert into bucket_max values (3500,'4000');
 insert into bucket_max values (4000,'4500');
 insert into bucket_max values (4500,'5000');
 insert into bucket_max values (5000,'Over 5000');
```

Then join using a >= based on the prior bucket amount to force a semi-Cartesian of the results. Example:

```
SELECT pb.pin, pb."MAX HOURS", bm.max_hours
FROM pa_btc pb
    left join
    bucket_max bm 
    on pb."MAX HOURS" >= bm.max_hours_val
;
```

This should give all values where the max hours meet the minimum for the bucket.